# Dynamic shaped div in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I make a div with a custom shape? I mean, I have a rectangular div by default, and a few shapes can be obtained by exploiting the border-radius property of the div, but what I am looking for is a semi-leaf shaped element, something like this:

[image]

The picture isn't all that great, but that's what I am looking for. The elements in the div should be placed in this shape. How do I attain such functionality?

I am not just looking for just a shape, but an element which is shaped this way which could hold more elements.

The major issue I am facing if I use border-radius as the solution is that, I have floated images inside this div, now if I use border-radius, it is either clipped as in Firefox or overflows out of its border as in [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browsers. How do I get this content to strictly be inside the shaped div?

Comment: This is rather difficult. Could you show us some context where this will be; it might help us come up with solutions.

Comment: This can be done with border-radius too

Comment: without HTML5 , its pretty difficult , why don't you go for a image which looks like that and write your text on top of that

Comment: I don't think what he's wanting can be done with `border-radius` alone.  It gets to the point where `border-radius` will simply make it look 'pill' shaped, not leaf shaped.

Comment: Its ok if i have the solution with html5 alone....

Comment: @Charles: See `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius`.

Comment: @minitech Even with those I don't think you're gonna be able to get `border-radius` to give you that gently angling effect.  The best you would be able to do with this is have one side with a rounded 'pill' effect.  Again, I don't think a rounded pill is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Charles: It looks right to me... http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/XHbhr/

Comment: @minitech Fair enough.  Thanks for the education.

Comment: I have a 300px width and 550px box which i wish to show like this, and there are floated images that are to go into this. When i scale your examples to this dimension, everything gets crazy.. and floated images also don't remain in the leaf div, please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the **shape of the div**, you can achieve that by tweaking the radii of the border angles using the CSS border-radius property:

```
width:25px;
height:200px;
background-color:#333;
border-top-left-radius:50px 200px;
border-bottom-left-radius:50px 200px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:50px 200px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:50px 200px;
```

Easy working solid div demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/83scc/1/

Doing it with just a border on a single div will NOT render well on a Mac - for example, if you just have a white background and a black border, the border will "cut out" and then "re-appear" due to the poor calculations of the [Bézier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and fill-ins. With just a background color (in the demo) it looks great. You could easily double up your divs, one white, and one 1 pixel larger black which sits underneath it, like so:

Working outline example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/83scc/3/

As far as the **contents of the div**, they won't naturally be positioned in such a way to compliment this shape, so you'll need to give them absolute positioning and give the parent an `overflow:hidden;` property.

Comment: Due to the decreased width you are getting close to the leaf structure.... i don't think that remains same when the width increases??

Comment: Sure it will, you just need to make sure the border radius values are set respective to the dimensions of the div. It can be any size you want.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no. A div can't do that for you. At least, not across all browsers. It is, and always will be, a rectangular element at heart (even with rounded corners).

If you want to draw something like that, you can use the cool new canvas tag and whip up some javascript magic. If you're looking for something that will actually hold things correctly (with padding and all that), then take a look at this: [Polygonal Divs -- Making content overflow in a specific shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961955/polygonal-divs-making-content-overflow-in-a-specific-shape)

I asked the same question a while ago in a slightly different  format. It has some good answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use percentages, to make it adjust to different sizes ;)

Try resizing this (in a browser that supports CSS resize) http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/XHbhr/1/ and observe how it changes to match its dimensions with no JavaScript whatsoever :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at mozilla's documentation about border-radius, they have pretty good examples:
[border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/border-radius)